# What does imposto/imposta mean in Italian?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

What does imposto/imposta mean in Italian?
Some people use the term  l'imposto when talking about vocal technique. 
What does it actually mean and how is it used in sentences?

Answer (score 2):

Do they use it speaking Italian, or as an Italian loanword in English?

Anyway, *imposto* as a noun doesn't mean anything related to vocal technique (unless it's a very technical term dictionaries don't know about). It's a past participle, meaning “imposed”. Perhaps they mean *impostazione*, which in this particular context may mean something like “(voice) placement”. There is also the corresponding verb, *impostare*, and *imposto* is its first person. So one might say *Imposto la voce* (“I place my voice”, if that is how you say it in English).

(*Imposta* is something completely different. Apart from being the feminine of *imposto*, it is a kind of tax or the shutter of a window.)

Comment: l'imposto or l'impostazione della voce is actually used when speaking about singing. https://books.google.se/books?id=fo94PekPbS0C&pg=PT116&lpg=PT116&dq=voce+imposto+canto&source=bl&ots=fIr5gPKwtW&sig=ACfU3U2sHcazfw4Y88TccjE74u2fTFpqJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz3bjM7frlAhVxk4sKHc5aBTwQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=voce%20imposto%20canto&f=false

Comment: After some googling it seems to be the name of a vocal training technique. My impression is that it is a sostantivization of the first person singular of *imporre* (non unheard of in Italian, cfr *il cambio*)

Comment: I have heard that "impostare" should be translated as "to impose". Is this true? Then imposta is something imposed. Tax is imposed. I do not see how "l'impostazione della voce" have to do with imposing. Please explain.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, _imposto_ (and its feminine form _imposta_) is indeed a past participle and its main meaning is “imposed”. They are forms of the verb _imporre_, meaning “to impose”. _Impostare_ is a different verb, which does _not_ mean “to impose”, but various things like “to plan / set up / lay out”, and is the one actually used with reference to voice.

Comment: @DenisNardin. If it's actually used, it seems more like a bespoke, zero-degree derivation from _impostare_ rather than _imporre_ (cambiare>cambio, impostare>imposto). Otherwise it should be _l'*impongo_.

Comment: @DaG Oops, you're right. That's what I meant.

Comment: @DenisNardin I’d say that *imposto* is used in the sense of *impostazione*